# Is there a way to promote a comment to an answer or accept a comment as the most useful?

Tags: discussion

Often, comments to my posted question are the most relevant to my understanding and subsequent solving of a problem. Sometimes, there are no answers posted, but I solved my issue through a comment.

I would like to a.) reward the poster with rep for being useful to me, and b.) increase my acceptance rate in cases where no answers have been posted. In most cases, I've asked the commenter to repost as an answer so I can accept it...to no avail.

Suggestions? Maybe after x days/weeks without answers, comments can be accepted as answers? Maybe a "promote to answer" option after x rep is earned? Maybe answering my own question with the comment and a way to manually award the "accepted answer" to the original commenter?

Answer (score 2):

Comments are a great way to scope requirements of the user asking the question. You can upvote comments if they are helpful. It's up to the user to post suggestions as answers, but I don't see an issue with answering your own question with the comment at hand after awhile if the user is unresponsive for a period of time.

Answer (score 2):

If the commenter hasn't added an answer after you've requested them to do so, then it's likely they're not to bothered over the reputation.

In this situation, it's best to add the answer yourself (with attribution to the original commenter). If you feel guilty about taking reputation for subsequent upvotes, mark the answer as Community Wiki.